# Context state being set with useEffect only setting the context to the last useEffect fired

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a smooth scroller by saving the refName.current.offsetTop value into context from multiple components.

- Context is currently only setting the last setState.
- My code looks like this, to keep from adding 2 components I ran
  multiple setSectionTops(sets context state) in useEffect.

**Component**

```js
const ProjectsList = () => {
  const {addSectionTop} = useContext(NavContext)
  let projectsRef = useRef()
  let ref2 = useRef()
  let ref3 = useRef()

  useEffect(()=>{
   addSectionTop('projects', projectsRef.current.offsetTop)
    addSectionTop('ref2', ref2.current.offsetTop)
    addSectionTop('ref3', ref3.current.offsetTop)
 
  },[])

  return (
    <section className="ProjectsList" id="ProjectsList" ref={projectsRef}>
      {/* {console.log('ProjectList:', navRefs)} */}
      <h2 ref={ref2}>Projects</h2>
      <div ref={ref3}>
        <Project />
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

**Context**

```js
export const NavContext = createContext()

const NavContextProvider = props => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)
  const [sectionTops, setSectionTops] = useState({})

  const toggleExpanded = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded)
  }
  const addSectionTop = (newNavStr, refOffsetTop) => {
    // console.log('sectionTops:',sectionTops)
    const newSectionTop = {[newNavStr]: refOffsetTop}
    // console.log('newNavRef:',newNavRef)
    setSectionTops({...sectionTops, ...newSectionTop})
    console.log(sectionTops)
  }

  const scrollTo = refKey => {
    const refOffSetTop = sectionTops[refKey]
    window.scrollTo({ top: refOffSetTop, behavior: 'smooth' })
  }

  const value = {
    expanded,
    toggleExpanded,
    sectionTops,
    addSectionTop,
    scrollTo
  }

  console.log(value)

  return (
    <NavContext.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</NavContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

At the end of this code all I in sectionTops: is {ref3: 799}.

1. Maybe I'm not understanding how useEffect works. From how I have it
   written with ,[] I was thinking it's equivalent to
   componentDidMount(). So to me it should load up the context with
   data once the component mounts.
2. Could it be a lifecycle problem in context b/c it does not have enough time to update state?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you got the last update is because you didn't use the callback pattern of the state updater, the state updater is asynchronous and should not take for granted to return the current state when multiple updates are running together.

When you try to spread `sectionTops` you are actually spreading the initial empty object in every `addSectionTop` call inside the effect.

It is recommended to always use the callback pattern when your state depends on the last state or when you make multiple state updates.

All you need to do is change to the state updater inside `addSectionTop` to use the callback pattern like this

```js
const addSectionTop = (newNavStr, refOffsetTop) => {
  setSectionTops(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [newNavStr]: refOffsetTop,
  }))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked and led me to reading much more about setState. I'm still having a hard time understanding where prevState is coming from. Is it inside setState? b/c it's batching the states before it renders them to prevent multiple renders.

Comment: @Krill React will call out callback function passing the current state as an argument